# SQLite Trigger to increment values conditionally

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I have a column that I would like to increment based on newly inserted/updated records, but what I've got so far is not working.

So my table `ProcedureCommands` has a column `Sequence` which is an integer. Whenever a new record is created with the `Sequence` value 5 for example, I would like all records that have the same `ProcedureId` and `Sequence` value >= 5 to be incremented by 1.

**Table Script**

```
CREATE TABLE ProcedureCommands (
ProcedureCommandId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                           NOT NULL,
ProcedureId        INTEGER NOT NULL,
Sequence           INTEGER NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO ProcedureCommands(ProcedureId, Sequence) VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT INTO ProcedureCommands(ProcedureId, Sequence) VALUES(1, 4);
INSERT INTO ProcedureCommands(ProcedureId, Sequence) VALUES(1, 5);
INSERT INTO ProcedureCommands(ProcedureId, Sequence) VALUES(1, 6);
INSERT INTO ProcedureCommands(ProcedureId, Sequence) VALUES(2, 4);
INSERT INTO ProcedureCommands(ProcedureId, Sequence) VALUES(2, 5);
```

**Trigger Script**

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update_Sequence UPDATE OF Sequence ON ProcedureCommands FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE ProcedureCommands
   SET Sequence = CASE WHEN Sequence >= new.Sequence THEN Sequence = Sequence + 1 ELSE Sequence END
 WHERE ProcedureId = new.ProcedureId;
END;
```

Unfortunately the Trigger as written does not work. How can I conditionally increment the field after inserts/updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trigger that handles new records is an INSERT trigger.

`Sequence = Sequence + 1` compares two values, and returns the result of the comparison. In this case, the two values can never be equal, so the result is always zero.

And you do not want to update the inserted row itself, so you must use `>` instead of `>=`.

If you do not want to update some rows, it is easier to put the filter into the WHERE clause:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update_Sequence
AFTER INSERT ON ProcedureCommands
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE ProcedureCommands
    SET Sequence = Sequence + 1
    WHERE ProcedureId = new.ProcedureId
      AND Sequence    > new.Sequence;
END;
```

Comment: Insert trigger working perfectly. I was able to use >= by adding an additional filter `ProcedureCommandId != new.ProcedureCommandId`. I am still confused on how to get this to work properly after an update though. I tried the following but the fields get incremented several times instead of by 1 `CREATE TRIGGER Refresh_Sequence_Update UPDATE OF Sequence ON ProcedureCommands
BEGIN    UPDATE ProcedureCommands SET Sequence = Sequence + 1
     WHERE ProcedureId = new.ProcedureId AND 
           Sequence >= new.Sequence AND 
           ProcedureCommandId != new.ProcedureCommandId;
END;
`

Comment: Disable [recursive triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_recursive_triggers). (Which, however, might be needed by other triggers in your DB.)

Comment: Thank you for the response but it seems I may be out of luck. I am using c# Entity Framework which does not seem to directly support the recursive triggers PRAGMA statement (it's not listed in the connection properties GUI and manually adding to the connection string does not change the behavior).

Comment: PRAGMAs are SQL statements that can be executed.